# Como dar um rollback no banco usando Spring Framework

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, spring, jpa, spring-boot

Tenho esse método que salva dados em 3 tabelas diferentes,

```
/**
 * 
 * @param user - de onde os dados do usuário serão retirados para gravar no banco
 * @throws GoogleAuthException - se houver algum erro ele retorna um erro a tela login
 * 
 * Este método cadastra um usuário com perfil geral, ele só será chamado se o usuário  não tiver nenhum perfil na tabela
 */
@Transactional
private Usuario cadastrarUsuario(GoogleUserInfo user) {

    Usuario usuario = new Usuario(user.getEmail(), user.getGiven_name(), user.getFamily_name(), StatusEnum.Ativo);
    Usuario usuarioSalvo = usuarioRepository.save(usuario);

    tracer.info(usuarioSalvo.toString());
    UsuarioPerfil usuarioPerfil = new UsuarioPerfil(RolesEnum.GERAL.getId(), usuarioSalvo.getIdUsuario(), Calendar.getInstance());
    usuarioPerfilRepository.save(usuarioPerfil);

    tracer.info(usuarioPerfil.toString());

    TelaUsuarioPerfilPrincipal telaPrincipalDoUsuario = 
            new TelaUsuarioPerfilPrincipal(usuarioSalvo.getIdUsuario(), RolesEnum.GERAL.getId(), ID_HOME_PAGE_PERFIL_GERAL);
    telaUsuarioPerfilPrincipalRepository.save(telaPrincipalDoUsuario);

    tracer.info(telaPrincipalDoUsuario.toString());

    return usuarioSalvo;
}
```

e gostaria de garantir a atomicidade dessas transações, eu gostaria que caso o segundo ou o terceiro save dessem erro os saves que deram certo dessem rollback no banco de dados e não fossem salvos, tentei usar a annotation `@Transactional` do Spring Boot porém não obtive sucesso.

Estas são minhas variáveis de acesso ao banco

```
@Autowired
private UsuarioRepository usuarioRepository;

@Autowired
private UsuarioPerfilRepository usuarioPerfilRepository;

@Autowired
private TelaUsuarioPerfilPrincipalRepository telaUsuarioPerfilPrincipalRepository;
```

Todas elas são interfaces que herdam de `JPARepository`.

Answer (score 2):

Por padrão, na ocorrência de um `RuntimeException` as alterações realizadas na transação sofrem Rollback (salvo exceção quando tratadas em um bloco `catch`), já as checked Exceptions não executarão rollback. Como pode ser visto na resposta para essa pergunta [Throwing a RuntimeException causes the transaction to rollback, but Exception doesn't in a spring boot app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29168786/throwing-a-runtimeexception-causes-the-transaction-to-rollback-but-exception-do), que faz referência a doc [Data Access](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#transaction) do Spring.

Caso você queira fazer rollback independente de qual a exceção lançada, é possível adicionar na anotação `@Transactional` quais devem realizar o rollback e quais não.
Ex:

```
@Transactional(rollbackOn = Exception.class)
public void start() {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Olá só pude testar sua resposta agora, porém não obtive sucesso no rollback eu fiz com que ele lançasse uma excessão logo após salvar o Usuário, porém ele não deu rollback na tabela de Usuario.

Comment: Por acaso, tais usando MongoDB?

Comment: Não MySQL mesmo.

Comment: Neste caso pesquisando um pouco mais sobre esse problema em aplicações Spring Boot com banco MySQL encontrei essa questão https://stackoverflow.com/a/49997835/8025145. Que teve como causa do problema a versão da Dialect do hibernate não mais suportada pela versão 2 do Spring. Vale a pena verificar se não é o seu caso.

Comment: E ai jovem? Problema resolvido?

Comment: me passaram outras atividades aqui na empresa e ainda não tive como voltar nisso, o único teste que pude fazer e que funcionou foi declarando explicatamente um `throw new RuntimeException()` ai ele deu rollback, mas no caso  de exceções normais não funcionou o rollback.